# Control the size of a modal layer of a dialog in android

Tags: android, dialog, modal-dialog

Can we control the area that a modal dialog blocks in a android? I have a custom dialog implementation that extends a ProgressDialog. It blocks the screen when the dialog is visible and can be cancelled on pressing the back button. I have navigation on the bottom of the screen and i want the dialog to not block them i.e rest of the screen is blocked and just the navigation still clickable so that if the user decides during loading of a screen that he wants to leave, he can. shouldnt have to wait for it to complete loading a screen he is not interested in. Can someone please point me to the right direction of how this can be achieved??